# Javascript sort array in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hi am working on a chat application, i want to sort new message plus keeping the history order according to time.

For example i have the chat messages in an array like this, now am sorting them using the "time" key on each message object!

```
[{"user":"a", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":1}
{"user":"b", "msg":"Hi ", "read":false, "time":2}
{"user":"c", "msg":"Hi ", "read":false, "time":3}
{"user":"d", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":4}
{"user":"e", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":5}]
```

How can i also sort them using the "read" key where all false values should come on the top but the remaining objects should be sorted with the "time" key.

For example like this

```
[{"user":"b", "msg":"Hi ", "read":false, "time":2}
{"user":"c", "msg":"Hi ", "read":false, "time":3}
{"user":"a", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":1}
{"user":"d", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":4}
{"user":"e", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":5}]
```

Comment: How are you sorting right now?

Comment: I would start by splitting the array into one with read messages and one with not read and then sort them independently. This way you can still use your finished sorter. Or are you looking for the specific code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and a callback for the sort order and chain the wanted sort parameter.

This callback uses the implicit converting of boolean to number with a calculation.

```js
var array = [{ "user": "a", "msg": "Hi ", "read": true, "time": 1 }, { "user": "b", "msg": "Hi ", "read": false, "time": 2 }, { "user": "c", "msg": "Hi ", "read": false, "time": 3 }, { "user": "d", "msg": "Hi ", "read": true, "time": 4 }, { "user": "e", "msg": "Hi ", "read": true, "time": 5 }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.read - b.read || a.time - b.time;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey i think you are doing it the other way round, false values need to go to the top

Comment: Super neat! i'd say it's a one liner

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{"user":"a", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":1},
{"user":"b", "msg":"Hi ", "read":false, "time":2},
{"user":"c", "msg":"Hi ", "read":false, "time":3},
{"user":"d", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":4},
{"user":"e", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":5}];

data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.read === b.read) {
    return a.time - b.time;
  }
  return a.read ? 1 : -1;
});

data.forEach(x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create to array one for red messages and another for unred ones. All the more so since messages are already sorted by time :

```
var chat = [{"user":"b", "msg":"Hi ", "read":false, "time":2}, {"user":"c", "msg":"Hi ", "read":false, "time":3}, {"user":"a", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":1}, {"user":"d", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":4}, {"user":"e", "msg":"Hi ", "read":true, "time":5}];

var chatRed = chat.filter(x => x.read);
var chatNotRed = chat.filter(x => !x.read);

console.log(chatNotRed);
console.log(chatRed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend sorting the `"read":false` and `"read:true` values separately if possible.

Otherwise, you can simply sort the array twice using a **stable** sort algorithm (like merge sort). First by 'time' key and then by 'read' key.

PS: Underscore js (https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore) provides a sortBy function which it claims is stable.

PPS: If you want to do this exactly with one sort, use a combination of the two keys `compare_key_generator = function(o){return o.read.toString()+o.time}`